# Regex to replace entire match

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I have this regex in JavaScript:

```
var val = val.replace(/[":)"]/g, "<img src = \"/img/smile.png\" height = 24 width = 24>");
```

Basically, this regex should replace `:)` with an image of a smiley, however it is placing an image of a smiley face on either `:` or `)` not when both are next to each other.

How must I adapt this regex: `/[":)"]/g` to only replace if there is an exact match for `:)` not just one on it's own?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have now is a character class, meaning it's looking to match either a `"`, `:`, or `)` and replace it with the image.

To fix this, your regex should be `/:\)/g`:

```
var val = val.replace(/:\)/g, "<img src = \"/img/smile.png\" height = 24 width = 24>");
```